# Autorenew vehicles openTTD

Tags: openttd

I am playing a scenario (Europe + Cities V2) and despite all settings being correct I can't have my vehicles renewed automatically. Is that because it is a scenario and not a "normal map"? I attached a picture of my settings (I am using version 1.5.1). 
If I can't get the autorenw to work I will have to stop my game as I am now spending my play time renewing my vehicles.
All suggestions welcomed.
All the best, 
Thierry[image: list of my old vehicles- not renewed]

Answer (score 10):

With the settings as shown above, vehicles should be automatically autorenewed. But for autorenewing, vehicles should be inside a depot.

Probably, your vehicles don't visit any depot. This happens when playing with breakdowns disabled and the setting "Disable servicing when breakdowns set to none: On". In this case, you can disable the former setting or send your vehicles to visit any depot (you can send all of them with a few clicks). Autorenewal of all vehicles will take some time.

Autorenewing can also fail if the vehicle has expired and you can't buy new ones. As you can renew vehicles individually, that may not be the case. See https://wiki.openttd.org/Never_expire_vehicles for more information.

In OpenTTD, you also must know that a vehicle can be:
1.- renewed: an old Hereford Leopard Bus is sold an a new one occupies its place.
2.- replaced with a different model (usually with better specs): ie Hereford Leopard Bus -> Foster Bus.

I think that in this case, you would like to autoreplace the vehicles instead of autorenew them. See:
https://wiki.openttd.org/Replace_vehicles

Answer (score 0):

I was changing the parameters in the main menu **before** loading the game. I did not know I could change the parameters once my own game was running.

Once my game was loaded, I changed the parameters, and it is all fine.

Comment: @Texenox, remember that we are here as a community. It takes less time to remove the thank you commentary then to post a comment telling OP not to include thank you commentary.

Comment: @Timelord64 ...huh? That's just the review comment, I didn't write that up myself.